# Is it possible to have a "Select All" option for a pickList input in AzureDevOps task?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

In a custom Azure DevOps release task, for an input of type pickList, is it possible to have a Select All option?Is there a property to enable that inside task.json?

Comment: You could easily add a record `All` and handle that input in your **Task** behind?

Comment: Hi MAK, Do you have any other concern about this ticket? If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for marking it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, seems you want a picklist in your task such as below:

[image]

Unfortunately, it's not supported for a multiple select picklist (include select all) right now.

Kindly refer our official task samples [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/6ca9a8995f22ed21f2ea6716673bb207dcac1c8f/Tasks/DotNetCoreCLIV2/task.json#L69).

You could also [file a feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea). Our PM will regularly review any suggestions.